# Selecting the lowest of 3 possible values across 3 Pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bit of a peculiar question that I have not found a working solution for. I am working with Pandas in Python.

I have three columns in a Pandas dataframe, e.g.:

```
x    y    z
3    6    9
5    nan  4
4    nan  nan
nan  nan  nan
```

I would like to create a fourth column that chooses the lowest possible value of the columns `x y z` in each row and reports it in a new column, or if missing, simply reports 'nan'.

The expected output would look something like this:

```
x    y    z    lowest
3    6    9    3
5    nan  4    4
4    nan  nan  4
nan  nan  nan  nan
```

I really don't even know where to begin with such a task, and finding the words to put it into a question is difficult. Thanks for your time! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`df.min()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) over `axis=1`:

```
df['lowest']=df.min(axis=1)
print(df)

     x    y    z  lowest
0  3.0  6.0  9.0     3.0
1  5.0  NaN  4.0     4.0
2  4.0  NaN  NaN     4.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Cheers! I'll mark this as answer in 5 mins (Stack is making me wait). I also have tons of other columns, but by using df['lowest'] = df.loc[:, ['x', 'y', 'z']].min(axis=1), I was able to select just the columns I needed. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @n0ro My pleasure..!! Glad i could be of help..!!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
df.assign(lowest=df.values.min(1))
```

df value will be as follows after running above command.

```
x   y   z   lowest
0   3.0 6.0 9.0 3.0
1   5.0 NaN 4.0 NaN
2   4.0 NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```